# Definite or indefinite integration of a relationship in physics

Tags: integration

When we have a relationship like the following

$$V=L\frac{di}{dt}$$

then in order to find the current $i$ we have to integrate.

My question is what how we choose what kind of integration we must apply. In some textbooks they integrate this very relationship like this:

$$i=\frac{1}{L}\int Vdt+c $$

and in some like this:

$$i=\frac{1}{L}\int_{t_{0}}^{t} Vd\tau+c $$

How do I choose if I have to integrate with indefinite or definite integral?

Comment: In the second integral the constant $c$ is plethoric. The value of the integral at $t_0$ is the constant of integration, i.e. the inital value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(t)$ an antiderivative of $V(t)$. The second integral is:
$$
\int_{t_0}^t V d \tau= F(t)-F(t_0)
$$
where $F(t_0)=k$ is a constant tha is the value of $F$ at the time $t_0$. So,  write
$$
\int_{t_0}^t V d \tau+c= F(t)-F(t_0)+c
$$
can have a sense only if you know that $c$ is the value of $F$ at some time different from $t_0$.

Anyway, The difference from 
$$
\int_{t_0}^t V d\tau 
$$
and
$$
\int V dt+c 
$$
is that in the first the value of constant of integreation is specified by the limit of integration $t_0$, in the second the value of the constat have to be specified by some added initial condition.